# Estimating Energy Bands For Dirac Comb Potential

Tags: electronic-band-theory

With 
$$V = \sum_n aV_0(x-na) $$

I can solve exactly up to
$$\cos(k a) = \cos(\kappa a) + \frac{2ma^2V_0}{\hbar^2}\frac{\sin(\kappa a)}{\kappa a} = f(\kappa a)$$
Where $E = \frac{\hbar^2 \kappa^2}{2m}$ and $k$ is the Bloch wavenumber. The goal is to solve for the gaps between the energy bands. Due to the transcendental nature we don't expect an exact solution, but can we get an approximate solution for the first few gaps without resorting to numerical methods?
A gap will be either

- start at $\kappa_1$: $f(\kappa_1 a) =1$ and $f'(\kappa_2 a) > 0$ and end at the next $\kappa$ where $f(\kappa_2 a) =1$ and $f'(\kappa_2 a) < 0$
- start at $\kappa_1$: $f(\kappa_1 a)= -1$ and $f'(\kappa_2 a) < 0$ and end at the next $\kappa$ where $f(\kappa_2 a) =-1$ and $f'(\kappa_2 a) > 0$

So maybe there is a way to approximate $f(\kappa a)$ for example that will enable estimating the size of the first couple band gaps?